# How to remove rust from desktop computer cabinet case

Tags: rust-removal

How to remove rust from desktop computer cabinet/ case?

I have 10 desktop PC and for 1 purchased cooler master premium cabinet which was expensive all if their side covers and internals are getting rusted I have googled and founded many chemicals but don't which one is safe and best which do not destroy the paint of the cabinets. I'm worried the rust don't catches in motherboard HDD or any other components

I have the following queries:

1. Which of chemical are good for rust removing and safe  secure and long lasting and does not cause rust again
2. How and what I can apply  can I protect cabinet so that it don't form rust again
3. How can I repaint the scratches after scrubbing the rust the cabinet which matches original paints does spray paint work as original
4. If it's a galvinised paint then why does rust form inside metal and outside covers can we do galvinised paints at home or market

Kindly guide or advice me with your suggestions and advice for rust free cabinets.

Comment: I think you should visit authorized service center, or computer repair shop so that they can help you better.

Comment: or a panel beater!

Comment: As far as the rust and a hard drive I would not worry they have a filter over there atmospheric port, I would be more concerned abought the moisture causing the rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original metal finish inside a PC it typically a type of zinc plating. no paint will exactly match it.

1: I don't know of any chemical that will remove rust without also attacking the plating. fish oil will stop the rust, but it take a long time to dry.

2: galvanised iron primer

3: take it to a paint shop, they'll probably be able to match the finish better than anyone can guess over the internet.

Consider going to a new finish, using automotive paints, you get a custom look at about the same expense as a repair.

It rusts because the zinc coating is applied to the sheet metal before the case is assembled, so all the cut edges have no plating. also something must be getting it wet, perhaps something causes condensation?

Comment: A zinc rich paint will also help once the rust is removed, rustoleum brand makes a paint that chemically neutralizes rust but  I preferred sanding or naval jelly to remove the rust then painting. I agree that matching plated zinc coating would be improbable for DIY.+

Comment: Naval Jelly is one of several products made from phosphoric acid which is a common rust remover.

Comment: [zinc reacts with phosphoric acid...|https://study.com/academy/answer/zinc-reacts-with-phosphoric-acid-h3po4-as-shown-in-equation-2-to-form-zinc-phosphate-and-hydrogen-gas-3zn-s-plus-2h3po4-aq-zn3-po4-2-aq-plus-3h2-g-equation-2-this-reaction-was-carried-out.html]